# Do astronauts on ISS get fresh perishable goods with deliveries?

Tags: iss, food

The usual fare for ISS has very long expiration dates, to last between deliveries, months apart. That, combined with other requirements (no crumbs/powders, no cooking, flatulence-safe etc) considerably limits the choice and surely impacts the taste.

But most delivery missions take below 3 days from launch to docking. Some take only 5-6 hours. Surely the astronauts would welcome food that is different from the usual preserved concentrates. Loading up a couple meals that are prepared shortly before launch, would expire in a couple days, but contain fresh produce shouldn't be that much of a deal.

Is it practiced? Or do astronauts eat the same stuff on the day of delivery as on the day before the next delivery?

Comment: Note that they (also?) [grow their own](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/08/science/spacex-resuming-deliveries-to-space-station.html)

Comment: Related, this documentary reveals some of the stringent rules on what's allowed on the ISS: http://www.channel4.com/programmes/hestons-dinner-in-space

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes they do. Here are some assorted quotes.

From [An Inside Look At How NASA Resupplies The International Space Station](http://observer.com/2015/11/an-inside-look-at-how-nasa-resupplies-the-international-space-station/):

> ...the menu includes whole fruit...

From [How does NASA transport food to the International Space Station? How often do they do it?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-NASA-transport-food-to-the-International-Space-Station-How-often-do-they-do-it):

> The fresh food locker contains tortillas, fresh bread, breakfast rolls, and fresh fruits and vegetables such as apples, bananas, oranges, and carrot and celery sticks

From [Nutrition in Spaceflight and Weightlessness Models](https://books.google.nl/books?id=Q-45xmPeimcC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=international+space+station+resupply+food+list+contents&source=bl&ots=1VdGdGveyh&sig=TY2sE8Hf3ntHDcOw8pM3rhSQdPA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih48CQ_rjNAhUmK8AKHckCAKcQ6AEIWDAJ#v=onepage&q=international%20space%20station%20resupply%20food%20list%20contents&f=false) (Helen W. Lane, Dale A. Schoeller) section 2.2.5 *International Space Station food*:

> Refrigerated items include fresh and fresh-treated fruits and vegetables...